# Unable to Receive User's Location: An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made

Tags: swift, ssl, networking

**Environment:** Xcode Version 12.5 beta 2 (12E5234g)

**Goal:** I want to access once/app the User's location to get the Country, State and County.

This had worked before, initially displaying an alert for user's acceptance for location; then proceed with acquiring the location.

**Problem:**
Today I'm not getting it. 
 I DO get the latitude & longitude coordinates; but not the reverse GeoCode Location.

I suspect it is the server because the request *times out*. 
I'm using my home Wifi (xFinity).

**Here's my code that times out:**

```
 private func getLocation(location: CLLocation) {
        CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location) { placemarks, _ in

            print("******  GLGeocoder Returns! (\(location))********")

            guard let placemark = placemarks?.first else {
                return
            }
            let country = placemark.country ?? ""
            UserLocation.country = country
            if placemark.administrativeArea != nil, USA.states != nil {
                UserLocation.state = USA.states![placemark.administrativeArea!]
            } else {
                NSLog("**** WARNING: Unable to access Location or State plist ****")
            }
            UserLocation.county = placemark.subAdministrativeArea
            UserLocation.coordinate = location.coordinate
            self.gotUserLocale = true
            print("My State: \(String(describing: UserLocation.state))")
        }
    }
```

Output after about 3 minutes:

```
******  GLGeocoder Returns! (<+36.97410000,-122.03080000> +/- 5.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/27/21, 11:28:49 AM Pacific Standard Time)********
******  GLGeocoder Returns! (<+36.97410000,-122.03080000> +/- 5.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/27/21, 11:28:49 AM Pacific Standard Time)********
******  GLGeocoder Returns! (<+36.97410000,-122.03080000> +/- 5.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/27/21, 11:28:49 AM Pacific Standard Time)********

Connection 1: received failure notification
Connection 1: failed to connect 3:-9816, reason -1
Connection 1: encountered error(3:-9816)
Connection 2: received failure notification
Connection 2: failed to connect 3:-9816, reason -1
Connection 2: encountered error(3:-9816)
[boringssl] boringssl_context_handle_fatal_alert(1800) [C3.1:2][0x127e2a4b0] read alert, level: fatal, description: inappropriate fallback
[boringssl] boringssl_session_handshake_incomplete(90) [C3.1:2][0x127e2a4b0] SSL library error
[boringssl] boringssl_session_handshake_error_print(41) [C3.1:2][0x127e2a4b0] Error: 4998591080:error:1000043e:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:TLSV1_ALERT_INAPPROPRIATE_FALLBACK:/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/boringssl_Sim/boringssl-351.100.8/ssl/tls_record.cc:594:SSL alert number 86
[boringssl] nw_protocol_boringssl_handshake_negotiate_proceed(767) [C3.1:2][0x127e2a4b0] handshake failed at state 12288: not completed
Connection 3: received failure notification
Connection 3: failed to connect 3:-9860, reason -1
Connection 3: encountered error(3:-9860)
Task <D87260CF-9E60-4355-8278-B2521BA3AF36>.<1> HTTP load failed, 0/0 bytes (error code: -1200 [3:-9860])
Task <D87260CF-9E60-4355-8278-B2521BA3AF36>.<1> finished with error [-1200] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/jhucsse, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <D87260CF-9E60-4355-8278-B2521BA3AF36>.<1>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <D87260CF-9E60-4355-8278-B2521BA3AF36>.<1>"
), NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made., NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/jhucsse, NSUnderlyingError=0x60000231db30 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1200 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9860, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9860}}, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9860}

JHUAll - Received error: #function URLError(_nsError: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/jhucsse, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <D87260CF-9E60-4355-8278-B2521BA3AF36>.<1>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <D87260CF-9E60-4355-8278-B2521BA3AF36>.<1>"
), NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made., NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/jhucsse, NSUnderlyingError=0x60000231db30 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1200 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9860, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9860}}, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9860})
```

I did the following test at the prompt which passed:

```
/Users/ric> nscurl --ats-diagnostics https://apple.com --verbose
```

Also note: **I can access** the public servers via Safari (copy/past URLs in error stmts).  But NOT via Xcode/application.

This was working before; but now it's not. 
What is causing this? 
**Solution?**

Also, how do I code to check for this in the future (e.g., reachability)? 
 I do get data from *public data sources* (public stats, etc.), but **I can't get the user's location** in particular.

BTW:  I just noticed this:

```
/Users/ric> swift --version                                                 
objc[1556]: Class AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x208551868) and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x1140442b8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[1556]: Class AMSupportURLSession is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x2085518b8) and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x114044308). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[1557]: Class AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x208551868) and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x1180442b8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[1557]: Class AMSupportURLSession is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x2085518b8) and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x118044308). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Apple Swift version 5.4 (swiftlang-1205.0.24.6 clang-1205.0.19.54)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin20.4.0
/Users/ric>
```

I ran 'swift' a 2nd time and it cleared:

```
/Users/ric> swift --version
Apple Swift version 5.4 (swiftlang-1205.0.24.6 clang-1205.0.19.54)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin20.4.0
/Users/ric>
```

**My Conclusion:** Bug at Apple side... perhaps their server is down?

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:** I was using Xcode Version 12.5 beta 2 (12E5234g). 
 It doesn't matter which command-line tools I've chosen.

**Solution:** Toss out Xcode beta and use the production-quality: Xcode Version 12.4 (12D4e).